# Pass Panel with constraints

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

How can I add a jpanel and also pass some constraints as well in jtabbedpane tabs.

```
addTab("name",null,here to pass panel but can't pass constraints, "tooltip");
```

More elaboration ...

When adding a jpanel in the tab the contents in the panel stretches all over the frame, so I decided to set the frame to GridBagLayout, but the when adding tab usually one has to pass a panel as one of the parameters, no constraints allowed! My question is how can I add constraints when adding panel in a tab  to exactly tell the frame where to place panel.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't, at least not with that version of the `addTab` method.  Anything that gets added to a `JTabbedPane` using that particular `addTab` method will get all available screen space when its associated tab is selected.

It sounds to me like you want to put more than one `Component` into the same tab, or change something about a component's resize behavior within that tab.  If this is the case, you should first add whatever components you want to visualize to an instance of `JPanel`, using the `panel.add(Component component,Object constraints)` method, then add that panel to the `JTabbedPane`.

Another option would be to do something like this:

```
JTabbedPane tabs = ...

int index = ... //whatever index you're currently at
Object constraints = ...//these are your constraints
JPanel panel = ...//this is the panel you want constraints for
panel.setName("name"); //will be used as the title when added to tabs in next line
tabs.add(panel, constraints, index);
tabs.setToolTipTextAt(index, "this is a tooltip for 'panel'");
```

Definitely not as appealing as a one-liner would be, but still gets the job done.

Comment: It still doesn't place the panel in the frame according to constraints I passed through!